# How often should I invest considering that each additional investment has a transaction fee?

Tags: optimization, finance, discrete-optimization

Today a friend opened a stock portfolio, asked me this and I started thinking about it instead of studying:

Let’s say you earn so much that you can save up $100$ € each day. If you invest the money in stocks you get $10$% plus each year on your investment, but investing an additional amount of money costs $25$ € in transaction fees. How often should you invest? It would of course not be reasonable to invest $100$ € each day because you’d loose $25$ € every time, on the other hand, waiting $10$ years is also stupid, because you’d be missing out on the exponential growth and you would only get a linear one. So what is the optimal strategy?

I think investing continuously would generate

$$
\int_0^t 100\cdot \exp\left[\ln(1.1){\frac{t-x}{365}}\right]dx
$$

in the time $t$, but is there a function to maximise if we now take the $25$ € into account, or is this a strictly discrete problem? Also I would assume that a periodic investment would be optimal, is that true? I‘ve never done any discrete optimisation, so I‘d be interested in what you all think:)

Comment: Those transaction fees seem prohibitively high.  On any given day, you only expect a yield of about $\exp(.01/365)$ on $N-25$ and that has to be $>N$ or else you do better by waiting.

Comment: Setting $\exp(.01/365)*(N-25)=N$ yields $N\approx 91262$, so you wouldn't invest for about $2.5$ years.

Comment: But doesn’t your reasoning assume that I want to make my 25 € back on a single day? I’d be happy to get them back after a week if that means a year of exponential growth afterwards

Comment: Oh, no.  Why should I invest at the beginning of the day when I'd have more in the evening if I simply waited? I can always invest tomorrow and I'll still have more than the version of me who invested today.

Comment: This is an important economic principal:  only invest if the marginal yield is positive.  Under a lot of assumptions, of course.  Primarily, under the assumption that I can invest whenever I want to without hurting my expected yield.

Comment: What you say makes sense but let’s say I invest the 1000: After a year I would have $1000\cdot1.1+100\cdot365-25$ if I hadn’t invested I would have $1000+100\cdot 365$ which is less. I’m getting confused now hahah

Comment: I should have said:  I am thinking of an investor who has a continuum of options and only tries to optimize local yield. If, on the other hand, you have an investor who is indifferent to current yield but seeks to optimize return over a specified horizon, then you get a different result.  But then you must specify a time horizon and apply the same computation I did to the new horizon.

Comment: As you remark, if your horizon is $1$ year, then you should invest $1000$ promptly, but you still shouldn't invest $100$ promptly because you'll do better by waiting.

Comment: This is interesting, so the optimal time of investment changes if this horizon changes? Does that mean that if the horizon is shifted further the optimal investment time approaches every day, every hour..? I’ll do some calculations tomorrow when I wake up:)

Comment: Absolutely.   As a practical matter, institutions with $100+$ year horizons (like university endowment plans) have a radically different view on investment strategies than typical investors.  But I wouldn't worry too much about exact time intervals.  All the numbers you are using are approximations anyway.  Rough computations are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems clear that you should invest periodically, because whatever is the right time to wait for the first investment after you make it you are starting  in the same place except you have this account that is growing.  We want to compare waiting $k$ days with waiting $k-1$ days and find where the crossover occurs.  We will look at the balance at the end of $n=k(k-1)$ days.  Define $i=1+\frac {0.1}{365}$ to be the daily interest factor

If we invest every $k$ days at the end of $k(k-1)$ days we have
$$(100k-25)\left(i^{n-k}+i^{n-2k}+i^{n-3k}\ldots+1\right)$$
where there are $k-1$ terms in the sum, one for each investment.  The first investment is made after $k$ days, so it compounds for $n-k$ days and so on.  We can sum the geometric series to get
$$(100k-25)\frac {i^n-1}{i^k-1}$$
Similarly, if we invest every $k-1$ days there are $k$ investments and $k$ terms in the sum.  We then have
$$(100(k-1)-25)\left(i^{n-k+1}+i^{n-2k+2}+i^{n-3k+3}\ldots+1\right)=(100(k-1)-25)\frac {i^n-1}{i^{k-1}-1}$$

I made a spreadsheet to compare these and the breakeven came at $43$ days.

Comment: Yes, thats it! Thank you! But why can’t we just maximise $(100k-25)\frac{i^n-1}{i^k-1}$ for a given n? This would also lead to about 44 days?

Comment: And if $n \rightarrow \infty$ does the functions maximum (for $k>0$) approach 0?

Comment: I wanted to use a complete number of cycles, so I chose the $n$ I did.  I think you could just maximize that.  The maximum is quite soft, so being off $43$ a few days doesn't matter much.  The $k$ that maximizes the function should not depend on what $n$ you pick.

Comment: Once more Lambert function ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

*There is an analytical solution to the problem*

Starting from @Ross Millikan's answer, writing
$$(100k-25)\frac {i^n-1}{i^k-1}=(100(k-1)-25)\frac {i^n-1}{i^{k-1}-1}$$ simplifying, we end with
$$\frac{(i^n-1)}{\left(i^k-1\right) \left(i^k-i\right)}\Big[(4 (i-1) k-5 i+1) i^k+4 i\Big]=0$$ and the solution is
$$k=\frac{5}{4}+\frac{1}{i-1}+\frac{1}{\log (i)}W\left(-\frac{i^{-\frac{i+3}{4 (i-1)}}}{i-1}\log (i)\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

For $i=1+\frac {0.1}{365}$, this gives exactly $k=43.3094$.

We can make *approximations* using $i=1+r^2$
$$k=\frac{1}{r\sqrt{2} }\left(1+\frac{7 }{6 \sqrt{2}}r+\frac{37 }{72}r^2+O\left(r^3\right) \right)$$ which, for $r^2=\frac 1 {3650}$ gives
$$k=\frac{7}{12}+\frac{262837}{720 \sqrt{73}}=43.3094$$

**Edit**

Making the problem more general, let $s$ the amount you can save and $c$ the commission fee, we have (with $a=\frac c s$)
$$k=\frac i{i-1} +a+\frac 1{\log(i)}W\left(-\frac{i^{\frac{1}{1-i}-a}}{i-1}\log(i)\right)$$ and, with $i=1+r^2$, the approximation
$$k = \frac{\sqrt{2a} }{r}+\frac{2 a+3}{6}+\frac{8 a^2+36 a+9}{72 \sqrt{2a}} r +\frac{2 a^2 }{135}r^2+O(r^3)$$